# txtProgressBar suddenly stopped working with style=3

Tags: r, progress-bar

I've been using `txtProgressBar()` for a while now. Since today, it stopped working if using `style=3`.
It just shows an empty progress bar, and is not updated.

Yesterday I updated some packages, but not the `utils` package, AFAIK. Maybe the sysadmins updated R without me knowing.

To reproduce:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
pb <- txtProgressBar(max = 11, style = 3)
Sys.sleep(1)
setTxtProgressBar(pb, pb$getVal()+1)
}
close(pb)
```

In my case, this just shows:

```
|                         |   0%
```

All the time. Other styles (1 and 2) work fine.

My R details:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu                                                                                                                                                                                                    
arch           x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
os             linux-gnu                                                                                                                                                                                                              
system         x86_64, linux-gnu                                                                                                                                                                                                      
status                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
major          3                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
minor          2.2                         
year           2015                        
month          08                          
day            14                          
svn rev        69053                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
nickname       Fire Safety
```

Is there something I'm missing, maybe something that could be wrongly set in my session, or is this a bug?

Comment: You put `pb <- txtProgressBar(max = 11, style = 3)` **inside** the loop. It should be **outside** the loop, before it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put `pb <- txtProgressBar(max = 11, style = 3)` **inside** the loop. It should be **outside** the loop, **before** it.
Also, your `max` is not correct. It should be 10, as your `for` loop goes from 1 to 10.

```
pb <- txtProgressBar(max = 10, style = 3)
for (i in 1:10) {
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, pb$getVal()+1)
}
close(pb)
```

Comment: Actually I'm a double idiot. First, for posting such a flawed question. Second, because it still doesn't work in my current application. The reason is that, I found,  I have a `mclapply()` call that calls a `pbStep(pb)` from package `raster`. This, for some reason, stopped working yesterday. Replacing it with `setTxtProgressBar(pb, pb$getVal()+1)` works well.

Answer (score 0):

the following part of the code: `pb <- txtProgressBar(max = 11, style = 3)`
should be outside the for loop. In my interpretation, if you put it inside you re-initialize the progress bar at each cycle of the loop.
The following code does what you are expecting:

```
pb <- txtProgressBar(max = 11, style = 3)
for (i in 1:10) {

  Sys.sleep(1)
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, pb$getVal()+1)
}
close(pb)
```